# Найти слово встречающееся чаще всего из списка словарей вида: `[('word1', 5), ('word2', 3)]`

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Изначально был словарь, в котором ключ - слово, значение - сколько раз это слово в тексте встречается. Надо получить какое слово встречается чаще всего. Пыталась сделать переводом в список и сортировкой, но список имеет такой вид:

```
[(a, 3), (am, 2), (her, 1)]
```

Как получить именно слово?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для ваших целей идеально подходит [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
In [1]: text = """Изначально был словарь, в котором ключ - слово, значение - сколько раз это слово
   ...: стречается чаще всего. Пыталась сделать переводом в список и сортировкой, но список имеет т

In [2]: from collections import Counter

In [3]: c = Counter(w.lower() for w in text.split() if w.isalpha())

In [4]: c.most_common(1)
Out[4]: [('в', 3)]
```

слово встречающееся чаще всего:

```
In [5]: c.most_common(1)[0][0]
Out[5]: 'в'
```

3 наиболее часто встречающихся слова:

```
In [6]: c.most_common(5)
Out[6]: [('в', 3), ('слово', 2), ('список', 2)]
```

---

Альтернативный вариант - поиск такого слова в списке словарей:

```
In [8]: items = [('a', 3), ('am', 2), ('her', 1)]

In [9]: max(items, key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[9]: ('a', 3)

In [10]: max(items, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
Out[10]: 'a'
```